# perform shell_exec over browser - raspberry pi

Tags: php, permissions, raspberry-pi, shell-exec

I want to run a PHP script from `chromium-browser` which will print a file. The file is located in `/tmp` folder on the Raspberry Pi. The file is copied from the server using SAMBA. The script has `shell_exec` command which attempts to do something with the file. The script works from the command line but not through the browser (chromium). I run the latest Stretch version of Raspbian.

I suspect it is something to do with permissions but I do not know where the problem is located. I have previous image Jessie with similar setup and functionality and it works. I compared all the permissions on both systems and they are exactly the same but I must be missing something.

Here is the PHP script:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
shell_exec("sudo lpr -P printerName /tmp/sample.pdf");
shell_exec("rm /tmp/sample.pdf");
?>
```

Here are related permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwt  15 root root  4096 Nov 23 16:17 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Nov  3 13:58 var

-rwxrw-rw- 1 nobody nogroup 320855 Nov 23 15:31 sample.pdf
```

Comment: Have you tried to `sudo chmod 777 sample.pdf' and see if that would work?  Not sure if you need execute permissions for printing a .pdf (I assume you only need read permissions) but I'm not exactly sure and I'm not sure what user:group you're under when your .php script runs shell_exec().

Comment: @cchoe1 I tried `sudo chmod 777 /tmp/sample.pdf` but it still does not work. It autologin as Pi and it opens a browser in KIOSK mode to print the file copied from the server. The file seems not be owned by anyone and have nogroup so I thought anyone can execute it.